# Got Django and Buildout working, but what about PIL and Postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-imaging-library, buildout

I'm on Mac OSX 10.5.8. I have followed Jacob Kaplan-Moss's article on setting up Django with Buildout: http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/

Finally, I have got this Buildout to work! ...but I'm now needing PIL and Postgres for a complete isolated Django development area. I've tried to modify my buildout.cfg with tutorials I've read around the internet, but just can't find how to do it without it throwing up all sorts of errors. I feel PIL and Postgres are the next things to complete this little setup, so I can just get on with it... (I'm not an expert at any of this by the way, I come from a PHP background). My current buildout.cfg looks like this:

```
[buildout]
parts = python django
develop = .
eggs = myproject

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
version = 1.1.1
project = myproject
projectegg = myproject
settings = testsettings
test = myproject
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
```

Can anyone help me to reliably get PIL and Postgres working with my Buildout? Thank you so much in advance... Everything I've tried so far just throws up all sorts of errors.

Comment: You should show what you tried and what errors you got.

Answer (score 8):

In theory, you should just be able to add `PIL` and `psycopg2` to your `eggs` directive:

```
eggs = myproject
       PIL
       psycopg2
```

This works on some systems and in some situations.

However, there are two problems that can prevent it from working everywhere, and especially on OSX:

1. `PIL`'s packaging is... weird in some way, and that can make installing it from PyPI fail.
2. Both `PIL` and `psycopg2` are C extensions, which means you'll need to have the correct shared libraries and header files before you can build and install them.

Fixing (1) is easy: just add

```
find-links = http://dist.plone.org/thirdparty/
```

To your `[buildout]` section. The Plone folks maintain an egg-ified `PIL` that Just Works™ with Buildout.

Fixing (2) is a bit more complicated and situation-depdendant: you'll need to make sure you've got all the various header files that `PIL` and `psycopg2` depend on.

### `psycopg2`

If you've installed PostgreSQL from the [PostgeSQL for Mac](http://www.postgresqlformac.com/) distribution (which I recommend), then it should have correctly installed the header files for you and `psycopg2` will build okay.

If you've installed PostgreSQL from source, then you'll have the header files already; `psycopg2` should build easily.

If, however, you've installed PostgreSQL some other way -- fink, ports, homebrew -- then you'll need to be careful and make sure you've got the development files install. In some package systems there's a separate `postgresql-dev` package with the development headers; others install those automatically.

If you've done this correctly, you should be able to run `pg_config` and verify that the `INCLUDEDIR` setting is set and correctly points to the header files (look for a `libpq` directory in the `INCLUDEDIR` directory).

### `PIL`

PIL's a lot more tricky because it depends on a lot more libraries. At the very least you'll need to install `libjpeg` and `libpng`. If you're on 10.6 they should already be installed for you; if not, the easiest thing is probably to download and install them from source: [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/), [libjpeg](http://www.ijg.org/).

Answer (score 0):

expanding on (2) above

PIL works with additional components that can be installed with below steps.

JPG

```
wget http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8b.tar.gz 
tar xzf jpegsrc.v8b.tar.gz 
cd jpeg-8b/ 
./configure 
make 
sudo make install
```

Freetype

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetype/files/ 
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/freetype/freetype2/2.4.4/freetype-2.4.4.tar.bz2 
tar xjf freetype-2.4.4.tar.bz2 
cd free* 
./configure 
make 
sudo make install
```

LittleCMS 1.19 (NOT 2.0+)

```
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lcms/lcms/1.19/lcms-1.19.tar.gz 
tar xzf lcms-1.19.tar.gz 
cd lcms*
./configure 
make 
sudo make install
```